# Meaning of "otherwise entitled"

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

Please help me understand the meaning of "otherwise entitled" in the following sentence:

> "Refusal to participate or stopping your participation will involve no penalty or loss of benefits to which you are **otherwise entitled**."

The above sentence is part of a consent form for a research on the access to medical services in a small town.

Comment: Your last explanatory sentence is a bit unclear. Consent for participation in what? In a medical research program? I'm afraid I don't understand " a research on the access to medical services".

Comment: It is a study of the access to medical services in a poor village. The words "study" and "research" are used interchangeably in the text.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the villagers who wish to participate in this study must first sign this consent form?

Comment: Yes, they must first sign the consent form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Refusal to participate or stopping your participation will involve no penalty or loss of benefits to which you are **otherwise entitled**."

If you have the right to some benefits and this right does not arise from your participation in the research program, you will not lose these benefits in case you refuse to participate or stop your participation in this program.

Say, you have the right to receive some prescription drugs free of charge. Then you learn about this new research program. Your right to receive these drugs is not linked to this program. You decide to participate in this new program, but then suddenly you change your mind and discontinue your participation. This decision will not affect your right to recieve the free drugs.

<sub>(caveat: I'm not a native speaker of English)</sub>

Comment: +1 Here is the same phrasing used in [CUHS adult consent form interview example](http://cuhs.harvard.edu/files/cuhs/files/cuhs_adult_interview_example_consent_form.doc) under "Participation is voluntary", in full: *It is your choice whether or not to participate in this research.  If you choose to participate, you may change your mind and leave the study at any time.  Refusal to participate or stopping your participation will involve no penalty or loss of benefits to which you are otherwise entitled.*